# In vb6 open .csv file with excel but day and month switching, why?

Tags: excel, csv, vb6

i develop program by vb6 to read data from .csv file and save it into db. i use excel application to open .csv file for reading, but in column date data is of day and  month are switch.

`objExcelAppl.Workbooks.Open FileName:=location, Delimiter:=",", ReadOnly:=False, Format:=xlCSV`

`ODate = objExcelAppl.ActiveSheet.Cells(RowOffset + i, 4).Value`

eg.

data : "11/01/2014"

but excel app read : "01/11/2014"

why? and  what  should i do?

Comment: 'objExcelAppl.Workbooks.Open FileName:=location, Delimiter:=",", ReadOnly:=False, Format:=xlCSV ODate = objExcelAppl.ActiveSheet.Cells(RowOffset + i, 4).Value' 

in notepad data is "11/01/2014" ,but when i read it with this code ODate > "01/11/2014"

Comment: [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) fixes the root cause for this :)

Comment: What is the correct date? What locale/date format is the machine configured to use and what format is Excel displaying it in? Note that VB6/VBA date literals are ALWAYS US format (`dd/mm/yyyy`). Displayed values should be in the system locale though.

Comment: when i open .csv file with ms excel date show "11/01/2014" but when i use excel app in my program it read "01/11/2014"

Answer (score 0):

I have facing similar problem before, but my case is when export data to excel, the day and month will switch.

I fix this issue by convert the date format to "yyyy-mm-dd" before send data to excel.

or since it's in csv file, you may just write a program to read it as text file and process the data line by line.